# What's the best Power Grid expansion for a beginner?

Tags: power-grid

What is the best Power Grid expansion for a beginner to buy?

Comment: Hello, Ender.  As written this question is likely to be closed - it's a purely subjective game recommendation with no possible "best answer".  You might try rephrasing it to redefine what you mean by "best" in an objective way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a beginner, I would say no expansion is necessary at all.  Vanilla Power Grid is an incredibly deep game.  I have found that it can be a bit overwhelming and introducing additional complexity will only make it harder.

Personally, some of my favorite games (Agricola and Dominion being two examples) I grew bored with the base game quickly and vastly prefer playing with the expansions.  Power Grid is not one of those games.  I have played it for years, and often still play just the base game even though I do own one of the expansions (Robots).

**Disclaimer:** I take a very analytic approach to board games.  More casual players might not find it as overwhelming as I do.